# Social Engine time display format

Tags: socialengine

I'm working on a Events module in SE4, and would like to display time/date in some particular format. This is the code i use now, for displaying event start time:
`echo $this->locale()->toTime($event->starttime);` and this code displays output `11.00` which is okay, but my question is: how to format this output?

Let's say I need output `11:00`, is there a way to format it that way?

Comment: quick 'n' dirty solution: `echo str_replace('.',':',$this->locale()->toTime($event->starttime));`

Comment: thanks, that did the job on this case, but would be grateful if there's a way to preformat it with built in method arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->locale()->toTime($event->starttime,array('format'=>'h:m'))
```